# Lard isn't sold anymore?

Tags: fat

Is lard being sold anymore?

I went to two different groceries, no lard, and no tallow.

(Shame on anyone who even thinks of telling me to use a hydrogenated oil.)

Comment: ... Why would we tell you to use hydrogenated oil? That wouldn't answer your question.

Comment: Do you have an Hispanic grocery in your area?  It should have it, labeled either as lard or manteca, and may be packaged in a tub (similar to the plastic tubs for margarine, cottage cheese etc.).

Comment: what country are you asking about? I find lard in the aisle with oils (not the fridge with butter and margarine) in Canadian grocery stores.

Comment: When all else fails, there is always Amazon https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lard

Comment: ...just checked the Walmart website for "In Store" lard. Bingo.. it's at my local Walmart https://www.walmart.com/ip/Armour-Lard-64-Oz/10449262 . Might be at yours if you are in the US. It may be in the Mexican section, it is popular for tamales and tortillas.

Comment: @Paulb I didn't think of checking Walmart. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen it in a lot of grocery stores either with the baking ingredients or at the meat counter. If your grocery store doesn't carry it, you might be able to request it. You might also be more likely to find it at an ethnic grocer, as it is traditionally used in tortillas, tamales, ramen, etc .